# Have SPSS output show the type1 label for BOTH sum and count rows?

Tags: spss

Is there a way to have table output for this statement show the type1 label for BOTH sum and count rows: "means renew1 cnt1 amnt1 by type1/cells=sum count."

Currently just shows the label in the top (Sum) row for each group of values and I'd like it where the yellow is also, in the "count" row.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tomAb.png)

Thank you!

Looked in Edit/Options/Output but not finding anything.